# How to fix error in model with gem lockbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using ruby '2.5.9' and rails '4.2.11.3'.
I configured all needed things for this gem. I have db with column "password_ciphertext", In model: "has_encrypted :password". When I type "Password" in rails console I have error: "NameError: undefined local variable or method `attributes_to_define_after_schema_loads' for Password"

Can you please explain what I am doing wrong

Comment: What version of lockbox are you using? I think your issue is that the class attribute referenced did not exist in rails 4.2.11

Comment: @engineersmnky I am using lockbox (0.6.8)

Comment: The internal attribute `attributes_to_define_after_schema_loads` was first introduced to Ruby on Rails 5.0. And it is worth noting that Rails 4.2 reach end of life in 2019, when the first version of the `lockbox` was released. It is not reasonable to expect that current gem versions should support Rails versions that are outdated for more than 3 years already. The version you are trying to use was released when Rails 7.0 was up-to-date. I suggest upgrading the Rails version in your application. Btw. Rails supports attribute encryption out of the box since 7.0 (released in 2021) too.